# Getting null session in spring startup class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

[Follow up to my existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160524/understanding-spring-singleton-to-load-entities-at-startup), I am getting null session factory and hence my transaction is being failed. Here is what my class structure looks like

```
@Component
public class MyCachingObj extends HibernateMapper{
    @PostConstruct
    public void loadAll() {
        ...
        getCurrentSession().getQuery(); //this method is in HibernateMapper
        ...
    }
}


@Repository
public class HibernateMapper {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory _session;

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return _session;
    }
}
```

What I have read so far, that `@PostConstruct` doesn't guarantee that spring is done with all beans. Then how can i make sure that spring is done processing and i have session ready to be picked up ?

**EDIT**
I ended up creating

```
@Component
@Transactional
@Repository
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{..}
```

which had autowired sessions and autowired another `Component` class. However, i noticed that this `onApplicationEvent` method was being called twice. I ended up putting a boolean variable to load the underlying data only once.

Now few questions

1. Why `onApplicationEvent` is being called twice.
2. My cached object is annotated with `@Component`, Is it safe to assume that as long as that object is being used by `@Autowired` instance, it would remain singleton and would hold the data i loaded at startup ?

Comment: You can create a Listener which is not called until all beans are initialized and add the necessary logic in that. See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686507/how-to-add-a-hook-to-the-application-context-initialization-event and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-events

Comment: Yup thats what I did, see updated post ... I have asked new questions in my edit.